# regex match when a combination of two words are present out of a list of words

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I'm looking for a regular expression that will:
Produce matches only when some combination of two words out of a list are present,

I’m currently using the following (part of a larger macro in VBA in Excel):

```
^(?!.*(word1)).*(word2|word3|word4).*$
```

to make matches that don’t include word 1 but include one of either word 2, 3 or 4.

What I need is to be able to change this so that it only makes matches when there is a combination of either word 2, 3, 4 (so some sort of AND statement)

So for example, we would get matches when there were the following combinations present:

```
Word 2, Word 3
Word 2, Word 4
Word 3, Word 4
```

Of course, I have more than 3 words, I have 16 different words that I need to run this process on.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I understood the request correctly, but this should work

```
^(?!.*word1)(?=.*(word2|word3|word4)).*
```